# Method comments does not exist

Tags: xampp, laravel-5.3

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method comments does not exist.

AdminPostsController.php

```
 public function post($slug){

    $post = Posts::where('slug', $slug)->get();

   // $post = Posts::findBySlugOrFail($slug);


    $comments = $post->comments()->whereIsActive(1)->get();


   return View('post', compact('post','comments'));


}
```

posts.php

```
public function comments(){


    return $this->hasMany("App\Comment",'post_id');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$post = Posts::where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

the **$post** variable contains a **Collection** object, not a **Post** object - that's why **comments()** method is not available. You can only call that method on a single post - changing **get()** to **first()** should get you a single post that matches the **slug** and then you should be able to fetch its comments:

```
$post = Posts::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$comments = $post->comments()->whereIsActive(1)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you it resolved. By adding slugHelper on module